# Inserting a value into a table, determining the minimum available

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table which holds information for users, the fields in this table are:

```
id (int) 
name (string)
```

I would like to be able to add a user, and providing him an ID that will be deferred from the current values that are in the table:

The ID that will be given to the added user should be the minimal that is available in the table i.e if I have a table with the following IDs: 1, 3, 4, 5, 8,
I would like the ID of the user to be 2, next time I'll add a user its ID will be 6, and the next one will be 7, and so on.

What would be the right query?

Comment: Why do you think you need that? A gapless ID is usually a bad idea because it's hard to implement correctly and if you do, it is extremely slow and does not scale in a multi-user environment

Comment: I need it because I want the I'd to be as ordered as possible. I don't care about speed and efficiency.

Comment: Why do you want them to be "ordered"? The **only** purpose of a primary key is to uniquely identify a row in a table. There is no need for the PK to be "ordered" (or even gapless). What is the real _problem_ you are trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into auth_user(id, user_name) 
values((select a from  generate_series((select min(id) from auth_user)
                                      ,(select max(id)+1 from auth_user)
                                      ) as a 
                       left join auth_user on (a = id )
                       where id is null order by a limit 1)
      , 'new user')
```

this is a bad idea, and its not transaction safe if you have simultaneous inserts

Answer (score 2):

Following select query can be used to find out missed ids from table

```
SELECT t
FROM generate_series((
            SELECT min(id) + 1
            FROM tb
            ), (
            SELECT max(id) + 1
            FROM tb
            )) t
WHERE NOT t IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM tb
        )
ORDER BY t ASC
```

and the insert can be done by following ways,

```
INSERT INTO tb
VALUES (
    (
        SELECT t
        FROM generate_series((
                    SELECT min(id) + 1
                    FROM tb
                    ), (
                    SELECT max(id) + 1
                    FROM tb
                    )) t
        WHERE NOT t IN (
                SELECT id
                FROM tb
                )
        ORDER BY t ASC limit 1
        )
    ,'B'
    )
```

OR

Create a function like this

```
    CREATE OR replace FUNCTION missed_id ()
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
SELECT t
FROM generate_series((
            SELECT min(id) + 1
            FROM tb
            ), (
            SELECT max(id) + 1
            FROM tb
            )) t
WHERE NOT t IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM tb
        )
ORDER BY t ASC limit 1;;$$
LANGUAGE sql
```

and insert should be

```
insert into tb values (missed_id(),'B')
```

Comment: and what if there is no missed id? :P

Comment: Boom will happen  if there are more than one missed id, you should do some limiting as well, and don't forget ordering :)

Comment: You forgot to `LOCK TABLE`. This can only be remotely safe if you lock the table first.